# Conda keeps trying to connect to a proxy even though it should be desabled

Tags: proxy, conda, environment

I'm trying to create a new environment with conda. Before, I was working behind a proxy and so I had it set on my .condarc file. But now, working at home, even though I've removed proxy related lines from .condarc, it keeps trying to connect to it when I try to create a new environment. This is my log:

```
> conda create -n my_env python=3.6 ipykernel -vvv

DEBUG conda.gateways.logging:set_verbosity(231): verbosity set to 3
DEBUG conda.core.solve:solve_final_state(223): solving prefix D:\Miniconda3\envs\my_env
  specs_to_remove: frozenset()
  specs_to_add: frozenset({MatchSpec("python=3.6"), MatchSpec("ipykernel")})
  prune: <auxlib._Null object at 0x000001E03753C808>
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): ...working... TRACE conda.gateways.disk.test:file_path_is_writable(25): checking path is writable D:\Miniconda3\pkgs\urls.txt
DEBUG conda.core.package_cache_data:_check_writable(259): package cache directory 'D:\Miniconda3\pkgs' writable: True
DEBUG conda.core.subdir_data:_load(241): Local cache timed out for https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64/current_repodata.json at D:\Miniconda3\pkgs\cache\9b8cd901.json
DEBUG conda.core.subdir_data:_load(241): Local cache timed out for https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/win-64/current_repodata.json at D:\Miniconda3\pkgs\cache\a9664645.json
DEBUG conda.core.subdir_data:_load(241): Local cache timed out for https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/win-64/current_repodata.json at D:\Miniconda3\pkgs\cache\f7597cf7.json
DEBUG conda.core.subdir_data:_load(241): Local cache timed out for https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/noarch/current_repodata.json at D:\Miniconda3\pkgs\cache\62c98390.json
DEBUG conda.core.subdir_data:_load(241): Local cache timed out for https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/win-64/current_repodata.json at D:\Miniconda3\pkgs\cache\1394f696.json
DEBUG conda.core.subdir_data:_load(241): Local cache timed out for https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch/current_repodata.json at D:\Miniconda3\pkgs\cache\b35683e8.json
DEBUG conda.core.subdir_data:_load(241): Local cache timed out for https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch/current_repodata.json at D:\Miniconda3\pkgs\cache\227b7582.json
DEBUG conda.core.subdir_data:_load(241): Local cache timed out for https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/noarch/current_repodata.json at D:\Miniconda3\pkgs\cache\e915db84.json
DEBUG urllib3.connectionpool:_new_conn(959): Starting new HTTPS connection (1): repo.anaconda.com:443
DEBUG urllib3.connectionpool:_new_conn(959): Starting new HTTPS connection (1): conda.anaconda.org:443
DEBUG urllib3.connectionpool:_new_conn(959): Starting new HTTPS connection (1): repo.anaconda.com:443
DEBUG urllib3.connectionpool:_new_conn(959): Starting new HTTPS connection (1): conda.anaconda.org:443
DEBUG urllib3.connectionpool:_new_conn(959): Starting new HTTPS connection (1): repo.anaconda.com:443
DEBUG urllib3.connectionpool:_new_conn(959): Starting new HTTPS connection (1): repo.anaconda.com:443
DEBUG urllib3.connectionpool:_new_conn(959): Starting new HTTPS connection (1): repo.anaconda.com:443
DEBUG urllib3.connectionpool:_new_conn(959): Starting new HTTPS connection (1): repo.anaconda.com:443
DEBUG urllib3.util.retry:increment(438): Incremented Retry for (url='/pkgs/msys2/noarch/current_repodata.json'): Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)
DEBUG urllib3.util.retry:increment(438): Incremented Retry for (url='/pkgs/main/win-64/current_repodata.json'): Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)
DEBUG urllib3.util.retry:increment(438): Incremented Retry for (url='/pkgs/msys2/win-64/current_repodata.json'): Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)
DEBUG urllib3.util.retry:increment(438): Incremented Retry for (url='/pkgs/main/noarch/current_repodata.json'): Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)
DEBUG urllib3.util.retry:increment(438): Incremented Retry for (url='/pkgs/r/noarch/current_repodata.json'): Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)
DEBUG urllib3.util.retry:increment(438): Incremented Retry for (url='/conda-forge/win-64/current_repodata.json'): Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)
DEBUG urllib3.util.retry:increment(438): Incremented Retry for (url='/pkgs/r/win-64/current_repodata.json'): Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)
WARNING urllib3.connectionpool:urlopen(745): Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x000001E038DE3148>, 'Connection to 172.31.219.30 timed out. (connect timeout=9.15)')': /pkgs/r/win-64/current_repodata.json
WARNING urllib3.connectionpool:urlopen(745): Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x000001E038DEB7C8>, 'Connection to 172.31.219.30 timed out. (connect timeout=9.15)')': /pkgs/msys2/noarch/current_repodata.json
WARNING urllib3.connectionpool:urlopen(745): Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x000001E03A137908>, 'Connection to 172.31.219.30 timed out. (connect timeout=9.15)')': /pkgs/main/win-64/current_repodata.json
WARNING urllib3.connectionpool:urlopen(745): Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x000001E038DE3DC8>, 'Connection to 172.31.219.30 timed out. (connect timeout=9.15)')': /pkgs/msys2/win-64/current_repodata.json
WARNING urllib3.connectionpool:urlopen(745): Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x000001E038DEBAC8>, 'Connection to 172.31.219.30 timed out. (connect timeout=9.15)')': /pkgs/main/noarch/current_repodata.json
WARNING urllib3.connectionpool:urlopen(745): Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x000001E038DEB2C8>, 'Connection to 172.31.219.30 timed out. (connect timeout=9.15)')': /pkgs/r/noarch/current_repodata.json
WARNING urllib3.connectionpool:urlopen(745): Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x000001E03A137D48>, 'Connection to 172.31.219.30 timed out. (connect timeout=9.15)')': /conda-forge/win-64/current_repodata.json
DEBUG urllib3.connectionpool:_new_conn(959): Starting new HTTPS connection (2): conda.anaconda.org:443
DEBUG urllib3.connectionpool:_new_conn(959): Starting new HTTPS connection (2): repo.anaconda.com:443
DEBUG urllib3.connectionpool:_new_conn(959): Starting new HTTPS connection (2): repo.anaconda.com:443
DEBUG urllib3.connectionpool:_new_conn(959): Starting new HTTPS connection (2): repo.anaconda.com:443
DEBUG urllib3.connectionpool:_new_conn(959): Starting new HTTPS connection (2): repo.anaconda.com:443
DEBUG urllib3.connectionpool:_new_conn(959): Starting new HTTPS connection (2): repo.anaconda.com:443
DEBUG urllib3.connectionpool:_new_conn(959): Starting new HTTPS connection (2): repo.anaconda.com:443
DEBUG urllib3.util.retry:increment(438): Incremented Retry for (url='/conda-forge/noarch/current_repodata.json'): Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)
WARNING urllib3.connectionpool:urlopen(745): Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x000001E038DE3788>, 'Connection to 172.31.219.30 timed out. (connect timeout=9.15)')': /conda-forge/noarch/current_repodata.json
DEBUG urllib3.connectionpool:_new_conn(959): Starting new HTTPS connection (2): conda.anaconda.org:443
DEBUG urllib3.util.retry:increment(438): Incremented Retry for (url='/conda-forge/win-64/current_repodata.json'): Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)
DEBUG urllib3.util.retry:increment(438): Incremented Retry for (url='/pkgs/r/win-64/current_repodata.json'): Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)
DEBUG urllib3.util.retry:increment(438): Incremented Retry for (url='/pkgs/msys2/noarch/current_repodata.json'): Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)
DEBUG urllib3.util.retry:increment(438): Incremented Retry for (url='/pkgs/main/win-64/current_repodata.json'): Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)
DEBUG urllib3.util.retry:increment(438): Incremented Retry for (url='/pkgs/msys2/win-64/current_repodata.json'): Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)
DEBUG urllib3.util.retry:increment(438): Incremented Retry for (url='/pkgs/main/noarch/current_repodata.json'): Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)
DEBUG urllib3.util.retry:increment(438): Incremented Retry for (url='/pkgs/r/noarch/current_repodata.json'): Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)
DEBUG urllib3.util.retry:increment(438): Incremented Retry for (url='/conda-forge/noarch/current_repodata.json'): Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)
WARNING urllib3.connectionpool:urlopen(745): Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x000001E038DF5808>, 'Connection to 172.31.219.30 timed out. (connect timeout=9.15)')': /conda-forge/win-64/current_repodata.json
DEBUG urllib3.connectionpool:_new_conn(959): Starting new HTTPS connection (3): conda.anaconda.org:443
WARNING urllib3.connectionpool:urlopen(745): Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x000001E038DF57C8>, 'Connection to 172.31.219.30 timed out. (connect timeout=9.15)')': /pkgs/r/win-64/current_repodata.json
DEBUG urllib3.connectionpool:_new_conn(959): Starting new HTTPS connection (3): repo.anaconda.com:443
WARNING urllib3.connectionpool:urlopen(745): Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x000001E038DF26C8>, 'Connection to 172.31.219.30 timed out. (connect timeout=9.15)')': /pkgs/msys2/noarch/current_repodata.json
DEBUG urllib3.connectionpool:_new_conn(959): Starting new HTTPS connection (3): repo.anaconda.com:443
WARNING urllib3.connectionpool:urlopen(745): Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x000001E038DF2AC8>, 'Connection to 172.31.219.30 timed out. (connect timeout=9.15)')': /pkgs/main/win-64/current_repodata.json
DEBUG urllib3.connectionpool:_new_conn(959): Starting new HTTPS connection (3): repo.anaconda.com:443
WARNING urllib3.connectionpool:urlopen(745): Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x000001E038DF2EC8>, 'Connection to 172.31.219.30 timed out. (connect timeout=9.15)')': /pkgs/msys2/win-64/current_repodata.json
DEBUG urllib3.connectionpool:_new_conn(959): Starting new HTTPS connection (3): repo.anaconda.com:443
WARNING urllib3.connectionpool:urlopen(745): Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x000001E038DF5248>, 'Connection to 172.31.219.30 timed out. (connect timeout=9.15)')': /pkgs/main/noarch/current_repodata.json
DEBUG urllib3.connectionpool:_new_conn(959): Starting new HTTPS connection (3): repo.anaconda.com:443
WARNING urllib3.connectionpool:urlopen(745): Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x000001E038DF5588>, 'Connection to 172.31.219.30 timed out. (connect timeout=9.15)')': /pkgs/r/noarch/current_repodata.json
DEBUG urllib3.connectionpool:_new_conn(959): Starting new HTTPS connection (3): repo.anaconda.com:443
WARNING urllib3.connectionpool:urlopen(745): Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x000001E038DF5B48>, 'Connection to 172.31.219.30 timed out. (connect timeout=9.15)')': /conda-forge/noarch/current_repodata.json
DEBUG urllib3.connectionpool:_new_conn(959): Starting new HTTPS connection (3): conda.anaconda.org:443
DEBUG urllib3.util.retry:increment(438): Incremented Retry for (url='/conda-forge/win-64/current_repodata.json'): Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)
DEBUG urllib3.util.retry:increment(438): Incremented Retry for (url='/pkgs/r/win-64/current_repodata.json'): Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)
DEBUG urllib3.util.retry:increment(438): Incremented Retry for (url='/pkgs/msys2/noarch/current_repodata.json'): Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)
DEBUG urllib3.util.retry:increment(438): Incremented Retry for (url='/pkgs/main/win-64/current_repodata.json'): Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)
DEBUG urllib3.util.retry:increment(438): Incremented Retry for (url='/pkgs/msys2/win-64/current_repodata.json'): Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)
DEBUG urllib3.util.retry:increment(438): Incremented Retry for (url='/pkgs/main/noarch/current_repodata.json'): Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)
DEBUG urllib3.util.retry:increment(438): Incremented Retry for (url='/pkgs/r/noarch/current_repodata.json'): Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)
DEBUG urllib3.util.retry:increment(438): Incremented Retry for (url='/conda-forge/noarch/current_repodata.json'): Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)
WARNING urllib3.connectionpool:urlopen(745): Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x000001E038DFEAC8>, 'Connection to 172.31.219.30 timed out. (connect timeout=9.15)')': /conda-forge/win-64/current_repodata.json
DEBUG urllib3.connectionpool:_new_conn(959): Starting new HTTPS connection (4): conda.anaconda.org:443
WARNING urllib3.connectionpool:urlopen(745): Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x000001E038DFEE08>, 'Connection to 172.31.219.30 timed out. (connect timeout=9.15)')': /pkgs/r/win-64/current_repodata.json
DEBUG urllib3.connectionpool:_new_conn(959): Starting new HTTPS connection (4): repo.anaconda.com:443
WARNING urllib3.connectionpool:urlopen(745): Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x000001E038E03288>, 'Connection to 172.31.219.30 timed out. (connect timeout=9.15)')': /pkgs/main/win-64/current_repodata.json
WARNING urllib3.connectionpool:urlopen(745): Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x000001E038E03088>, 'Connection to 172.31.219.30 timed out. (connect timeout=9.15)')': /pkgs/msys2/noarch/current_repodata.json
WARNING urllib3.connectionpool:urlopen(745): Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x000001E038E03488>, 'Connection to 172.31.219.30 timed out. (connect timeout=9.15)')': /pkgs/msys2/win-64/current_repodata.json
WARNING urllib3.connectionpool:urlopen(745): Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x000001E038E03688>, 'Connection to 172.31.219.30 timed out. (connect timeout=9.15)')': /pkgs/main/noarch/current_repodata.json
WARNING urllib3.connectionpool:urlopen(745): Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x000001E038E03848>, 'Connection to 172.31.219.30 timed out. (connect timeout=9.15)')': /pkgs/r/noarch/current_repodata.json
WARNING urllib3.connectionpool:urlopen(745): Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x000001E038E03A88>, 'Connection to 172.31.219.30 timed out. (connect timeout=9.15)')': /conda-forge/noarch/current_repodata.json
DEBUG urllib3.connectionpool:_new_conn(959): Starting new HTTPS connection (4): repo.anaconda.com:443
DEBUG urllib3.connectionpool:_new_conn(959): Starting new HTTPS connection (4): repo.anaconda.com:443
DEBUG urllib3.connectionpool:_new_conn(959): Starting new HTTPS connection (4): repo.anaconda.com:443
DEBUG urllib3.connectionpool:_new_conn(959): Starting new HTTPS connection (4): repo.anaconda.com:443
DEBUG urllib3.connectionpool:_new_conn(959): Starting new HTTPS connection (4): repo.anaconda.com:443
DEBUG urllib3.connectionpool:_new_conn(959): Starting new HTTPS connection (4): conda.anaconda.org:443
failed
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 157, in _new_conn
    (self._dns_host, self.port), self.timeout, **extra_kw
  File "D:\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\connection.py", line 84, in create_connection
    raise err
  File "D:\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\connection.py", line 74, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)
socket.timeout: timed out

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 662, in urlopen
    self._prepare_proxy(conn)
  File "D:\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 948, in _prepare_proxy
    conn.connect()
  File "D:\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 300, in connect
    conn = self._new_conn()
  File "D:\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 164, in _new_conn
    % (self.host, self.timeout),
urllib3.exceptions.ConnectTimeoutError: (<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x000001E038E0A208>, 'Connection to 172.31.219.30 timed out. (connect timeout=9.15)')

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 449, in send
    timeout=timeout
  File "D:\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 760, in urlopen
    **response_kw
  File "D:\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 760, in urlopen
    **response_kw
  File "D:\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 760, in urlopen
    **response_kw
  File "D:\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 720, in urlopen
    method, url, error=e, _pool=self, _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2]
  File "D:\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\retry.py", line 436, in increment
    raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='conda.anaconda.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /conda-forge/win-64/current_repodata.json (Caused by ConnectTimeoutError(<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x000001E038E0A208>, 'Connection to 172.31.219.30 timed out. (connect timeout=9.15)'))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\core\subdir_data.py", line 485, in fetch_repodata_remote_request
    timeout=timeout)
  File "D:\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 546, in get
    return self.request('GET', url, **kwargs)
  File "D:\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 533, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "D:\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 646, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "D:\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 504, in send
    raise ConnectTimeout(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectTimeout: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='conda.anaconda.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /conda-forge/win-64/current_repodata.json (Caused by ConnectTimeoutError(<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x000001E038E0A208>, 'Connection to 172.31.219.30 timed out. (connect timeout=9.15)'))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\exceptions.py", line 1079, in __call__
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\cli\main.py", line 84, in _main
    exit_code = do_call(args, p)
  File "D:\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\cli\conda_argparse.py", line 82, in do_call
    return getattr(module, func_name)(args, parser)
  File "D:\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\cli\main_create.py", line 37, in execute
    install(args, parser, 'create')
  File "D:\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\cli\install.py", line 265, in install
    should_retry_solve=(_should_retry_unfrozen or repodata_fn != repodata_fns[-1]),
  File "D:\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\core\solve.py", line 117, in solve_for_transaction
    should_retry_solve)
  File "D:\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\core\solve.py", line 158, in solve_for_diff
    force_remove, should_retry_solve)
  File "D:\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\core\solve.py", line 262, in solve_final_state
    ssc = self._collect_all_metadata(ssc)
  File "D:\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\common\io.py", line 88, in decorated
    return f(*args, **kwds)
  File "D:\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\core\solve.py", line 415, in _collect_all_metadata
    index, r = self._prepare(prepared_specs)
  File "D:\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\core\solve.py", line 1011, in _prepare
    self.subdirs, prepared_specs, self._repodata_fn)
  File "D:\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\core\index.py", line 228, in get_reduced_index
    repodata_fn=repodata_fn)
  File "D:\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\core\subdir_data.py", line 105, in query_all
    result = tuple(concat(executor.map(subdir_query, channel_urls)))
  File "D:\Miniconda3\lib\concurrent\futures\_base.py", line 598, in result_iterator
    yield fs.pop().result()
  File "D:\Miniconda3\lib\concurrent\futures\_base.py", line 435, in result
    return self.__get_result()
  File "D:\Miniconda3\lib\concurrent\futures\_base.py", line 384, in __get_result
    raise self._exception
  File "D:\Miniconda3\lib\concurrent\futures\thread.py", line 57, in run
    result = self.fn(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
  File "D:\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\core\subdir_data.py", line 98, in <lambda>
    package_ref_or_match_spec))
  File "D:\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\core\subdir_data.py", line 110, in query
    self.load()
  File "D:\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\core\subdir_data.py", line 174, in load
    _internal_state = self._load()
  File "D:\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\core\subdir_data.py", line 248, in _load
    repodata_fn=self.repodata_fn)
  File "D:\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\core\subdir_data.py", line 595, in fetch_repodata_remote_request
    caused_by=e)
conda.exceptions.CondaHTTPError: HTTP 000 CONNECTION FAILED for url <https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/win-64/current_repodata.json>
Elapsed: -

An HTTP error occurred when trying to retrieve this URL.
HTTP errors are often intermittent, and a simple retry will get you on your way.
'https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/win-64'
```

Thanks everyone for your time.

UPDATE:
If I run `conda info --all`, proxies values are "":

```
HTTPS_PROXY: <set>
HTTP_PROXY: <set>
```

With `conda config --remove-key proxy_servers.http` and `conda config --remove-key proxy_servers.https` it says that those keys don't exist (because they don't, I've removed them from `.condarc`). I've I set them back and run those commands, they are removed from `.condarc` but the problem remains.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't forget to check your windows environment variables.

There might cause the error.